# Flipping axis ticks

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I edit the axes of an image in MATLAB to reverse the direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865600/how-do-i-edit-the-axes-of-an-image-in-matlab-to-reverse-the-direction)

Hey guys,

In MatLab I have a pair of axes where the y-axis starts from (0,0) and counts up to (0,100) with tick marks on this x-axis going 0,1,2,...,100.  Can a flip it so it goes 100,99,...,0 **so the origin would be (0,100)**?  Any ideas?  I know it's possible because I've seen graph figures like this.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865600/how-do-i-edit-the-axes-of-an-image-in-matlab-to-reverse-the-direction

Answer (score 2):

`set(gca,'YDir','reverse');` before you draw the graph.  Thanks to gary comtois's link - stackoverflow.com/questions/2865600/