# How can I get the negative side to ppoint upward on an ordinate in Matalb?

Tags: matlab, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I edit the axes of an image in MATLAB to reverse the direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865600/how-do-i-edit-the-axes-of-an-image-in-matlab-to-reverse-the-direction)

For an engineering plot I need to have the negative side of the y-ordinate point upward. Simply speaking, I need to invert the y-axis. How can I do that?

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I edit the axes of an image in MATLAB to reverse the direction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865600/how-do-i-edit-the-axes-of-an-image-in-matlab-to-reverse-the-direction)

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically, you can call

```
set(gca,'YDir','reverse')
```

Alternatively, you can select the arrow in the figure window, double-click on the axes, and click the 'reverse' checkbox in the plot editor for the y-axis.