# Matlab - reverse value of axis in plot

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I edit the axes of an image in MATLAB to reverse the direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865600/how-do-i-edit-the-axes-of-an-image-in-matlab-to-reverse-the-direction)

[image]

The colour image is plotted using the `image` function based on some information obtained using `imread` function and for the white and blue image basically I am selecting the coordinates of the heat point(red and blue and their variations basically) from the map and then displaying them using `plot` function. 
 
 The problem is that the plotted values are reversed on the Y axis and I can't figure out how to reverse the Y axis of the plot in order to obtain the same correlation between the images.

Could you please explain me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, matlab draws graphs with (0,0) at the bottom left corner. However, it draw images with (0,0) in the top-left corner.

You can change the image axes to standard bottom-left origin by using the command

```
axis xy;
```

Remember to make sure that your image is the currently selected figure.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rot90()` to rotate the matrix, or a combination or `fliplr()` (flips matrix, left and right) and `flipud()` (flips matrix up and down) that produced the heat map image.

If you are plotting an image and you don't want to see the axis tic marks you can turn them off with

```
axis off
```

if you are interested in changing the direction of either the *x*-axis and/or *y*-axis in an axes handle-object, you can use the *set* function as follows

```
set(axesHandle,'XDir','rev','YDir','rev')
```

where you use XDir or YDir (or both) based on the axis you want reversed.

Comment: This is a plotting problem, not a matrix rotation problem.