# In Matlab, how to change axis orientation?

Tags: matlab

I have been writing a script in Matlab that plots 3D images, by using `plot3`.

The axis are run in this interval:

- x: [1 -> 0]
- y: [0.01 -> 0]
- z: [0 -> 1]

The result is provided in this figure:

[image]

Now I would like to change the orientation of my axis, and replot the figure with this axis orientation:

- x: [0 -> 1]
- y: [0 -> 0.01]
- z: [0 -> 1]

How could I do this?

Thanx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2865600/623518

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the direction of an axis by setting the appropriate direction property, see the `XDir, YDir, ZDir` properties in the [Axes Properties documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html). These properties have the value `normal` or `reverse`. To reverse the direction of one of your axis, say the x-axis, use

```
set(gca, 'XDir', 'reverse')
```