# Flip single axis in 3d coordinate system

Tags: ilnumerics

Usually the axis in a 3d plot form a right system, in the mathematical sense. 
For some plots I would like to reverse an axis, usually the y-axis, so that the data is actually plotted as if a mirror transformation would have been done on the hyper-plane {y = 0}.
How could that be done most easily? Can it done directly on the axis, by appropriate settings? Or do I really have to mirror the data?

I searched and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623700/how-to-configure-the-scale-label-position-in-ilnumerics) but it does not what I need, it just rotates the view, but does not orient the axis different. This get's closer but is buggy to as the labels are not properly attached to the axis ticks:

```
    plotcube.Axes.YAxis.Scale(1.0, -1.0, 1.0) |> ignore
    plotcube.Axes.YAxis.Translate(0.0, 1.0, 0.0) |> ignore
    surface.Scale(1.0, -1.0, 1.0) |> ignore
```

In Matlab I would just do it [that way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632859/in-matlab-how-to-change-axis-orientation).

Many thanks for a suggestion or solution.

Comment: Have you tried this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502759/how-to-reverse-the-axis-in-ilnumerics

Comment: Yes I know this post. But that does not solve the problem. I want to reverse the axis as it is done with the matlab cmd set(gca, 'XDir', 'reverse'). I experimented with              plotcube.Axes.YAxis.Scale(1.0, -1.0, 1.0); 
surface.Scale(1.0, -1.0, 1.0); but then the Y axis are off. How do I make the axis ok? The surface is properly mirrored. I think there should be a function at the plot cube level to do that as in matlab. For a single surface I can do the transform easily, but for more complicated plots it is not so convenient.

Comment: In which way is the answer from the other thread not suitable?

Comment: It just rotates the cube with all the data in it. I need to reflect at say y = 0. I can do that for each plotting element, like point and surface. but then I also need to change the axis. And if I just to also a plotcube.Axes.YAxis.Scale(1.0, -1.0, 1.0). I would have screen shots, but I cannot add them here. Shall I send them by mail or open a new question?

Comment: I still don't get how flipping the axis is different to rotating the plot cube? Do you want to reverse the axis but let the content stay the same? Any screenshots would be really helpful. Consider using http://ilnumerics.net/direct-support.html